How to compress images client side before uploading with Livewire

I'm working on a project using Livewire 3 and I'm encountering issues
with large image files from modern cell phones, as these
high-megapixel images are too heavy to be handled efficiently on slow
connections.
I want to compress images on the client side before uploading them via
Livewire. Additionally, I'd love to see an example of integrating
JavaScript with Livewire for this purpose, as such examples are quite
rare or outdated.
I'm comfortable with the "Laravel way" of uploading and previewing
images with Livewire 3, but I'm not familiar with the JavaScript
integration part, so I'm having a hard time uploading and previewing
the JavaScript-compressed files with Livewire.
I know that there are some popular JS packages for this purpose, like
Compressor.js or
Browser Image
Compression
or that we can also achieve this with plain old JS - I would just like
a working example, no matter which JavaScript compression method is
used.
Has anyone dealt with this issue before? How can I achieve client-side
image compression and upload the compressed image using Livewire?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

----- EDIT -----
While I appreciate the suggestions regarding client-side image compression scripts like Compressor.js or Browser Image Compression, what I specifically need assistance with is integrating the compressed images seamlessly with Livewire for preview and upload purposes.
Here's what I'm struggling with:

Client-Side Compression: I understand how to use JavaScript to compress images on the client side before uploading them. However, I'm unsure about the next steps in terms of handling these compressed images within a Livewire component.
Previewing Compressed Images: Once an image is compressed on the client side, how can I ensure that the Livewire component can properly preview it before upload? Do I need to manipulate the DOM directly within Livewire, or is there a more elegant way to achieve this?
Uploading Compressed Images via Livewire: After the user selects and compresses an image, how can I ensure that the Livewire component receives the compressed image data for uploading? Are there specific Livewire methods or approaches I should be aware of for handling compressed image data?

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or examples demonstrating how to seamlessly integrate client-side compressed images with Livewire, particularly within the context of a file upload component.
Thank you again for your assistance!

compressorjs has a working example live demo. They also have working examples in the GitHub repo.

Thank you for your answer but what I really need help with is in making Livewire use this compressed image for the preview and upload.

You can do it with compress.js
async function resizeImageFn(file) {

    const resizedImage = await compress.compress([file], {
      size: 2, // the max size in MB, defaults to 2MB
      quality: 1, // the quality of the image, max is 1,
      maxWidth: 300, // the max width of the output image, defaults to 1920px
      maxHeight: 300, // the max height of the output image, defaults to 1920px
      resize: true // defaults to true, set false if you do not want to resize the image width and height
    })
    const img = resizedImage[0];
    const base64str = img.data
    const imgExt = img.ext
    const resizedFiile = Compress.convertBase64ToFile(base64str, imgExt)
    return resizedFiile;
  }


Thank you for your answer but what I really need help with is in making Livewire use this compressed image for the preview and upload.


When a user selects a file, Livewire’s JavaScript requests a temporary “signed” upload URL from the server.
JavaScript then uploads the file to the signed URL, storing it temporarily.
Livewire generates a unique hash ID for the uploaded file.
Finally, the server sets the public property (e.g., $photo) to the temporary file.

Note: First you have to store generated file to default photos directory or customized location. than provide that path to livewire for uploading
